# How to dynamically generate C# class at compile time?

Tags: c#, code-generation, fody

For example, I have written a `SomeEntity` class:

```
class SomeEntity
{
    public object Content { get; set; }
}
```

I want my project to automatically generate the code for another class based on the `SomeEntity`:

```
class SomeProvider
{
    public SomeEntity GetEntity(object content) => new SomeEntity { Content = content };
}
```

*This is just a simple demo, the logic of real requirements is much more complicated than this.*

In my cognition, this is like **Protobuf** generates the corresponding class according to the `.proto` file, and the generated class can be correctly recognized by the IDE (the class is generated in `obj` dir, how to impl it?).

I have tried **Fody**, but it seems that the injected object cannot be recognized by the IDE.

What is the best technical principle & solution?

Comment: Have a look at [T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Fody technique when some codes are injected,IDE and compiler would not be aware of it. I recommend Rosyln which is intended to do the exact thing and much more. Take a look at this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview

For comparing different available source code generation for .net here is a good article:
https://dominikjeske.github.io/source-generators/